# Using Class in Javascript instead of ID

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just copied some code in javascript, but it doesn't actually working because what I had is "class" not "id". document.getElementById("classname"). how do you do it in JS using "class" it is not recognized that's why my JS failed, there is another way of using class in JS ?

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "25px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "80px 10px";
    document.getElementById("logo").style.fontSize = "35px";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("example");

Answer (score 1):

When you reference an HTML element by id you use `document.getElementById()`. When you reference an HTML element by class you use `document.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that where `ID` is supposed to be unique, `class` is not – it's actually one of the very reason to use it.

So they're not equivalent. However, you can target a selector using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):  the first method returns the first element to match the given selector, so you might use that:

```
const element = document.querySelector(".myclass");
```